# Call Javascript Function from .ascx file

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one javascript function named 'change2()' which is define in **.ascx** page's script tag.
I want to call that function from onclick event of **img** tag (Note : img tag is also on the same page). 
It is compulsory to use img tag only for image.
I tried all the below ways, but unfortunately It doesn't work for me.

Test.ascx

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function change2() {
            alert("Hi");
        } 
    </script>




  <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="list">
               Most liked
          </td>
          <td>
              <img id="imgLkU" src='<%# WebHelper.GetBaseURL(Request) + "/images/slide_btn_down.png"%>'class="icon_right_panel" runat="server" onclick="change2();" alt="Slider" />
           </td>
          </tr>
     </table>
```

Second Way :

```
<table>
            <tr>
              <td class="list">
                   Most liked
              </td>
              <td>
                  <a href="#" onclick="change2();"><img id="imgLkU" src='<%# WebHelper.GetBaseURL(Request) + "/images/slide_btn_down.png"%>'class="icon_right_panel" runat="server"  alt="Slider" /></a>
               </td>
              </tr>
         </table>
```

Please give me your suggestions to call javascript function from same page.

Comment: What is your problem? this should work.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi no, it shouldn't. see http://forums.asp.net/t/1249580.aspx?onclick+versus+onclientclick

Comment: I did not get any error but function is not called.

Comment: you should use `onclientclick` then `onclick`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see, the `img` id is `imgLkU`, so, instead of including the call in the `img` tag itself, you can subscribe the event "from the outside", i.e. do it like using [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/), (or [$.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)) like this:

```
$.on('click','#imgLkU', function() { change2(); });
// or equivalent  $.on('click','#imgLkU', change2);
```

or

```
$.('#imgLkU').click(function() { change2(); });
// or equivalent $.('#imgLkU').click(change2);
```

Do it right after defining `change2` in the same script tag.

I'd also recommend you doing the `change2` definition and the event subscription inside an  [inmediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to avoid polluting the global javascript namespace.

```
(function() { 
   // define and subscribe here
 })();
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But It is still not working.

Comment: have you debugged it in the browser's console? Please, begud it in the browser, check that $('#imgLkU') is not empty. Then click it with a breakpoint in change2. Pay attentiton to errors in the console

Comment: Thanks bro.. It works fine for me. Also there was one mistake by me i.e. I wrote Document.ready two times by mistake and placed this code in second  document.ready part. I combined both part and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Because your elements all have `runat="server"`, their `onclick` property is  reserved for a backend-code actionlistener which will be executed at postback.

the `onClientClick` property is reserved to allow you to still attach javascript "listeners" to what is considered the client-side `onclick`.

keep in mind that returning `false` from an `onClientClick` handler will prevent postback from happening if an `onclick` listener is also hooked up. (`onClientclick` is executed before initiating the postback)

try this :

```
<img id="imgLkU" src='<%# WebHelper.GetBaseURL(Request) + "/images/slide_btn_down.png"%>'class="icon_right_panel" runat="server" onclientclick="change2();" alt="Slider" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The following function can be directly called from `document.ready` function like

```
$(function () {
    $('#imgLkU').click(function () {
        //do what ever you want
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, take out the `runat="server"` on your image since you are already using server tags to set the url. If you still want to use `runat="server"`, you can either:

1: change your img into an `<asp:Image>` tag and use `ImageSource` instead of `src` and `OnClientClick` instead of `onclick`.

2: set the `src` attribute in the code behind.

After that, any click method - from your question to all the answers - should work.

If that *still* does not show the alert, then start taking out code until it does and work your way from there...